# How to bring the last 5 register of each ID with SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have a table with the purchase registers. There are all the purchase registers of a Pet Shop, since 2010. 
I need some help to bring only the last five purchase of each client.

I was trying, but it is not working. It brings me the last 5 registers of all the table, and not of each client.

```sql
SELECT TOP (5) [client_name],
        [purchase_date],
        [item]
FROM [Pet_Shop]
ORDER BY client_name 
WHERE client_name in ('John', 'Mary', 'Austin')
```

I need this kind of return:

```
client_name | purchase_date | item 
___________________________________
John        | 2019-09-14    | food
John        | 2019-09-13    | ball
John        | 2019-09-12    | shampoo
John        | 2019-09-11    | cookie
John        | 2019-09-11    | food
Mary        | 2019-09-14    | collar
Mary        | 2019-07-14    | food
Mary        | 2019-06-14    | toy
Mary        | 2019-06-14    | hamster
Mary        | 2019-05-14    | food
Austin      | 2019-09-18    | food
Austin      | 2019-09-11    | collar
Austin      | 2019-09-10    | toy
Austin      | 2019-09-09    | catnip
Austin      | 2019-09-11    | food
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        client_name,
        purchase_date,
        item,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY client_name ORDER BY purchase_date desc) rn
    FROM Pet_Shop
    WHERE client_name in ('John', 'Mary', 'Austin')
) x
WHERE rn <= 5
ORDER BY client_name
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! I tried it, but I had this as a return: ```The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.```

Comment: @Marshallowitz: I moved the `ORDER BY` clause to the outer query. This should work fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CROSS APPLY like this:

```
DECLARE @Registry TABLE (client_name VARCHAR(100), purchase_date DATETIME,  item INT)
INSERT INTO @Registry
(client_name, purchase_date, item)
VALUES
('Client1', '1/1/2019', 1), 
('Client1', '2/1/2019', 2),
('Client1', '3/1/2019', 3),
('Client1', '4/1/2019', 4),
('Client1', '5/1/2019', 5),
('Client1', '6/1/2019', 6),
('Client1', '7/1/2019', 7),
('Client2', '1/1/2019', 1), 
('Client2', '2/1/2019', 2),
('Client2', '3/1/2019', 3),
('Client2', '4/1/2019', 4),
('Client2', '5/1/2019', 5),
('Client2', '6/1/2019', 6),
('Client2', '7/1/2019', 7)

;WITH Clients AS (
    SELECT client_name FROM @Registry GROUP BY client_name
)
SELECT C.*, P.purchase_date, P.item
    FROM Clients AS C
    CROSS APPLY 
    (
        SELECT TOP 5 R.purchase_date, R.item 
        FROM @Registry R 
        WHERE R.client_name = C.client_name
        ORDER BY R.purchase_date DESC
    ) P
ORDER BY C.client_name, P.purchase_date, P.item
```

Here is the result:

```
client_name purchase_date   item
Client1 2019-03-01 00:00:00.000 3
Client1 2019-04-01 00:00:00.000 4
Client1 2019-05-01 00:00:00.000 5
Client1 2019-06-01 00:00:00.000 6
Client1 2019-07-01 00:00:00.000 7
Client2 2019-03-01 00:00:00.000 3
Client2 2019-04-01 00:00:00.000 4
Client2 2019-05-01 00:00:00.000 5
Client2 2019-06-01 00:00:00.000 6
Client2 2019-07-01 00:00:00.000 7
```